# Is there core-ajax in Polymer 0.8?

Tags: polymer

In Polymer.js 0.5 I was writing:

Now, I want to go to new version - 0.8 but I can't find core-ajax in 0.8 version.
Is there way to use core-ajax in 0.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 0.8 preview element for core-Ajax on github. https://github.com/Polymer/core-ajax/tree/0.8-preview?files=1

Comment: https://github.com/polymerelements/iron-ajax is more up to date. The core- elements are being moved and renamed. Stay tuned!